# Sparse Extreme Learning Machine

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, svm

I tried to develop code for sparse ELM proposed by following paper. I used random hidden neurone kernel. and sigmoid activation function.

But the code is not performing well in terms of time. It is taking much more than expected time to get trained .

I think there is some problem in updating **d**

Paper :- http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/egbhuang/pdf/Sparse-ELM-IEEE-T-Cybernetics.pdf

Here is my code implementation :-

```
    function [model]=selm2(tr,tr_c,L,seed,C)
    [N, In] = size(tr);

    [tempH, W_ih, BiasofHiddenNeurons]=Selm_Hiddenoutput(tr,L, 'sigmoid',seed);
    H=[tempH ones(N,1)];

    delta = H*H';


    % f=funcpredict(alpha,tr_c,tr,delta);


    G=(tr_c*tr_c').*delta;

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% algo starts %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    alpha=zeros(N,1);
    g=G*alpha-1;
    J=g;
    d=ones(N,1);

    while min(J(:))<-(10^-3)
        J=g.*d;
        [mini ind]=min(J);
        %     temp=G*alpha;
        alpha(ind)=alpha(ind) + ((-g(ind))/delta(ind,ind));


        if alpha(ind)<0
            alpha(ind)=0;
        elseif alpha(ind)>C
            alpha(ind)=C;
        end
        g=G*alpha-1;

        d=-sign(g);
        d(alpha==C)=-1;
        d(alpha==0)=1;
    % %     for i=1:N
    %         if alpha(ind)==0
    %             d(ind)=1;
    %         elseif alpha(ind)==C
    %             d(ind)=-1;
    % %         else
    % %             d(ind)= -sign(g(i));
    %         end
    %     end


    end
    support= (alpha~=0);
    supportvec=[tr(support,:) tr_c(support)];




model.wih=W_ih;
model.bias=BiasofHiddenNeurons;
model.alpha=alpha(support);
model.vectors=supportvec;
```

Comment: Have you used the profiler to figure out which part is taking the most time?

Comment: yes !!!  updation of 'd' is taking most time.

Comment: @nkjt I used profiler which says that  g=G*alpha-1; is taking most time. but as it is necessary to update it so it does not need to be changed. The second most time consuming statement is  d=-sign(g);